# Android analytics sdk for Android doesn't work

Tags: android, google-analytics

I'm trying to use Google analytics in my Android app.
So, I've created a new test app in my Google analytics account and linked my app to it.

This is the code I'm using to do so

In my activity

```
tracker = GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance();
tracker.startNewSession("UA-xxxx-yy", 1, this);
```

In the fragment (or page)

```
((TestActivity)getActivity()).tracker.trackPageView("/blah");// + data.name);
((TestActivity)getActivity()).tracker.trackEvent("stam", "succeed", "yes", 2);
((TestActivity)getActivity()).tracker.dispatch();
```

But for some reason I see nothing on my account. Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Out of curiosity, how long has it been since you added analytics and started monitoring for the data?

Comment: Google Analytics can take [up to 24 hours](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/frequently-google-analytics-update-33562.html) to show

Comment: It is already been 24 hours and yet nothing

Comment: I'm having the same problem right now. I'm going to wait and track this question.

Comment: Check logcat messages: is there any messages similar to `Problem with socket or streams` or `NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond`? Google Analytics panel has real-time tracking (beta) at 'Home' tab. Is there any avtivity? Have you tried emulator or other devices?

Comment: Well, I get http response 200 so I'm guessing it foes send it to Google, but I see nothing in Google analytics's site not even in the real time tracking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your Google Analytics SDK: libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar worked for me (not libGoogleAnalytics.jar).

Here are the docs https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/
According to docs you should use `EasyTracker` or `GoogleAnalytics` instead of `GoogleAnalyticsTracker`

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStart(this); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I created my analytics account as mobile app, and this is probably only working with sdkv2. So I've crated a new one and this time I used website settings and now it works great.

Comment: @VokilaM com.google.android.apps.analytics.GoogleAnalytics is not compatible with libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar